# OperationContext usage (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage

I'm going to download blob from Azure Blob Storage to stream and I need to specify retry policy and timeouts. That's why I use the *BlobRequestOptions* (WindowsAzure.Storage NuGet package) instance to specify all these settings. I also want to use the asynchronous method *DownloadToStreamAsync* that needs some additional parameters to be passed (AccessCondition, OperationContext). My code:

```
var selfieBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(GetBlobUri(requestedUrl), _credentials);
await selfieBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(
    targetStream,
    AccessCondition.GenerateEmptyCondition(),
    _blobOptions,
    new OperationContext());
```

Questions:

- Should I create a new instance of OperationContext each time?
- Why is it a required parameter for this method? Seems I don't understand why it's so necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the method `DownloadToStreamAsync` with `default(OperationContext)`. This is the same being done by other overloads of `DownloadToStreamAsync`. Check [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Blob/CloudBlob.cs#L277)

```
await selfieBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(
    targetStream,
    default(AccessCondition),
    _blobOptions,
    default(OperationContext));
```

It's usually used for logging correlation. Check `ExcecuteAsync` method implementation [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/cbe605f9faa01bfc3003d75fc5a16b2eaccfe102/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Core/Executor/Executor.cs#L48).

Answer (score 1):

About the `OperationContext` parameter, *@user1672994*'s answer is right.

Refer to the [`CloudBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync` Method's description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadtostreamasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_DownloadToStreamAsync_System_IO_Stream_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_OperationContext_), you could know why the parameter `AccessCondition` is required. You could set it to be `null` if you don't have the condition limitation.